# macOS 10.12; Configure: error: failed to find required module google.protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, macports

Using MacPorts to try and install OLA for work. Came across this error when trying to build OLA after getting it from github:

> checking for python module: google.protobuf... no
>
> configure: error: failed to find required module google.protobuf

Tried googling around to see if there was a solution, didn't find one. Like the title implies, I'm on a Macbook Air running Sierra, Python version is 2.7.10.

Answer (score 2):

MacPorts has a port for OLA.  Installing it will automatically install the required protobuf module.

Command is `sudo port install ola`

Or is there some reason that you need to install a version from GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably a missing package un your python installation, if you have `pip` installed you can do something like:

```
$ python -m pip install google.protobuf
```

This of course inside a terminal of your system. Check out this link for more information:

[Installing Packages Documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)